# CSS3 infinite loop animation

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create CSS/HTML banner with infinite loop animation similar to this http://attasi.com/labs/picsselz.

Here is the copied code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjpx5p1r/).

My banner is fullwidth, it should occupy complete width of the screen. But currently, the sample animation has fixed width wrapper.

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 588px;
    margin-left: -600px;
    margin-top: -300px;
    background: #9cfcf0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now if I set wrapper width to 100% its spreads but some animated elements disappear over the time. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjpx5p1r/3/)

[image]

How can I make above-mentioned CSS3 animation work well on full-width screen ?

Answer (score 0):

So as you can see that all the images are literally created on their own css attributes... actually super amazing imho**....

But if you change the `.wrapper` to `100%` width then you are going to have to realize that he used set values. He intended everything to be set by a specific parameter. In your case your screen is wider than the 2400px he set for the ground.

Set the ground value or any value you find that seems to disappear to some greater width. I set it to 2600px in my case as it only disappeared by about 50 px and it worked perfectly.

I did not see any other styles that disappear, but I am sure this will work for all cases.

**This is much less amazing now that I realize it was designed and built using a tool called MACAW. now macaw could be awesome and amazing, but it likely took much less time than I had previously believed. Still pretty amazing, but keep that in mind.

Comment: Yes, its nice animation. But your solution didn't work. I need make this work on any resolution in full width.

Comment: did you by chance try it in the fiddle or no? It didn't work in fiddle but worked in the browser I had. Not sure what was different though.